# Showing that locally bounded family of functions is locally lipschitz

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

[image]

This is an exercise in Conway. Here $G$ is an open set of the complex plane, C(G,{C}) is the set of all continuous functions from $G$ to the complex plane and $H(G)$ is the set of all analytic functions on $G$. I managed to show (b), but am stuck at (c). I think I have to use the definition of derivatives of the analytic functions but can't proceed on. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $D = D_r(z_0)$ is a disk with $\overline D \subset G$ then for $a, b \in D$
[Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) gives
$$
 f(a) - f(b) = \frac{a-b}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz \, .
$$
It follows that if $\cal F$ is uniformly bounded on $D$ then 
it is uniformly Lipschitz on $D_{r/2}(z_0)$.